# Spring-Cloud configuration server ignores configuration properties file

Tags: java, spring-cloud

I am trying to create a Spring Cloud configuration server which reads the configuration data from the properties file and not a github. The server starts, but does not serve the properties from the file. I have two configuration files on the classpapath:

bootstrap.yml

```
spring:
application:
    name: config-server
```

config-server.properties

```
foo=bar
```

when I go to the url which supposedly should give me the value of the foo property:

```
curl  http://localhost:8888/admin/env/foo
```

I get an error:
"timestamp":1415298615005,"status":404,"error":"Not Found","exception":"org.springframework.boot.actuate.endpoint.mvc.EnvironmentMvcEndpoint$NoSuchPropertyException","message":"No such property: foo","path":"/admin/env/foo"}

I am wondering what I am doing wrong? As far as I understand the properties file name should match the server name in order to be recognized by the server.

---

adding native profile as spencergibb suggested did not help. my application.properties looks like:

```
server.port=8888
spring.profiles.active=native
spring.config.name=configserver
spring.application.name=configserver
```

**Note, that I had to specify the server port. According to Spring Cloud Config Server documentation the configuration server starts on port 8888 by default. In my case however unless I specify the port in my config the server starts at 8080.**

The POM file has no parent and a single dependency:

```
    <dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-cloud-config-server</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.0.M2</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

The application has nothing special in it:

```
@Configuration
@ComponentScan
@EnableAutoConfiguration
@EnableConfigServer
public class ConfigurationApp {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(ConfigurationApp.class, args);
    }
}
```

The configserver.properties file contains a single entry: foo=bar

First of all I am always getting a startup error

```
2014-11-07 09:35:42.852 ERROR 6972 --- [           main] b.c.PropertySourceBootstrapConfiguration : Could not locate PropertySource: I/O error on GET request for "http://localhost:8888/configserver/default/master":Connection refused: connect; nested exception is java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect
```

Regardless of which command I execute I am always getting the same response from the server:

```
{"name":"info","label":"master","propertySources":[{"name":"bootstrap","source":{}},{"name":"applicationConfig: [classpath:/application.properties]","source":{"spring.config.name":"configserver","spring.application.name":"configserver","server.port":"8888","spring.profiles.active":"native"}},{"name":"defaultProperties","source":{"spring.application.name":"bootstrap"}}]}
```

I tried:

```
http://localhost:8888/configserver/env
http://localhost:8888/configserver/env/foo
http://localhost:8888/configserver/info
http://localhost:8888/configserver/beans
http://localhost:8888/configserver/health
```

The response is always as above

Answer (score 5):

By default, the config server serves properties from git.  You will need to set the profile to `native` using `--spring.profiles.active=native` for the configserver to serve the spring environment.  The `spring.config.name` for the config server is programmatically set to `spring.config.name=configserver` so your properties file will need to be configserver.properties.

Comment: I added the setting you suggested to application.properties. The error went away, but I am still unable to get my properties. I updated my original post with more info

Comment: I tried accessing the configserver properties by using path e.g. http://localhost:8888/spring-boot-config-client/default/master and it worked. Check tutorial https://www.tutorialspoint.com/spring_boot/spring_boot_cloud_configuration_server.htm @MrkK

Answer (score 1):

The "/admin/env" endpoint in a config server only serves the local configuration of the server itself. The server is usually just a regular Spring Boot app, so it gets its configuration from "application.properties". If you want to pick it up from "config-server.properties" you need to set "spring.config.name" or "spring.config.location" (just like a normal Boot app).