# Spring cloud config with Subversion backend

Tags: spring, spring-cloud

is this possible? What about Perforce? I would need to use one of these or a file based and check it in with the crontab or something.

Answer (score 4):

It is certainly possible to implement SVN or Perforce.  You would need to implement [EnvironmentRepository](https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-config/blob/master/spring-cloud-config-server/src/main/java/org/springframework/cloud/config/server/EnvironmentRepository.java).  See [JGitEnvironmentRepository](https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-config/blob/master/spring-cloud-config-server/src/main/java/org/springframework/cloud/config/server/JGitEnvironmentRepository.java) for an example.

See this question for working with local files: [Spring Cloud Configuration Server not working with local properties file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27131143/spring-cloud-configuration-server-not-working-with-local-properties-file/27159030)

Answer (score 3):

I have been working on getting SVN as a backend working.

There is support for this in spring config since March 2015 and the following is needed

1. Add a dependency on svnkit to your pom.xml
2. Change the profile to subversion
3. Your svn structure must be trunk/property-files

   `<dependency>
       <groupId>org.tmatesoft.svnkit</groupId>
       <artifactId>svnkit</artifactId>
   </dependency>`

   `profiles:
     active: subversion`

A sample file is here https://github.com/spring-cloud-samples/svn-config-server

The property files are loaded in this order

```
<appname>-<profile>.(properties|yml)
<appname>.(properties|yml)
application.(properties|yml)
```