# Spring config server refresh properties from local config file

Tags: spring-cloud-config

In my Spring Cloud application I would like to let user to change some default settings. I keep the default properties in application.yml inside the jar and start my application with

```
-Dspring.config.additional-location=/some_location/properties_override.yml
```

When the user changes properties_override.yml I wanted to reload configuration without restarting the application. Spring config server seems to be an ideal mechanism for it, but I cannot figure out if it can work with the properties located locally on the file system. When I am looking at spring.cloud.config it seems to only only support git, jdbc and svn servers. None of these mechanisms is an option for me I am wondering if thee is a way to use Spring Cloud Config to reload configuration from a local file on the file system?

Using "native" profile seems to be a right way to go, but it created another problem: I need two entries in cloud.config.server.native.searchLocations: one for application.yml on the classpath (in module's src\main\resources\config folder) and the second one on the file path.
Setting searchLocations to:

```
 searchLocations: classpath:/config,file:/some_location/properties_override.yml
```

The properties in application.yml are not picked up.

If my application.yml I have entry

```
custom:
  property: foo
```

There is a Spring bean which has property tagged with

```
@Value("${custom.property"})
```

Without searchLocations in application.yml the property is being resolved. With searchLocations I am getting an exception:

```
 java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Could not resolve placeholder 'custom.property' in value "${custom.property}"
at org.springframework.util.PropertyPlaceholderHelper.parseStringValue(PropertyPlaceholderHelper.java:172) ~[spring-core-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.util.PropertyPlaceholderHelper.replacePlaceholders(PropertyPlaceholderHelper.java:124) ~[spring-core-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.core.env.AbstractPropertyResolver.doResolvePlaceholders(AbstractPropertyResolver.java:237) ~[spring-core-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.core.env.AbstractPropertyResolver.resolveRequiredPlaceholders(AbstractPropertyResolver.java:211) ~[spring-core-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.context.support.PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer.lambda$processProperties$0(PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer.java:175) ~[spring-context-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
```

Answer (score 3):

Setting up a filesystem-based repository is the easiest way to
accomplish this.
Use `spring.profiles.active=native` this should work. 
Here is an example using a yml file:

```
server:
  port: 8888
spring:
  profiles:
    active: native
  cloud:
    config:
      server:
        native:
          searchLocations: file:///Users/gurinder/projects/application-name/configserver/src/main/resources/config/yourservice
```

And also check this link [stackoverflow-question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27131143/spring-cloud-configuration-server-not-working-with-local-properties-file).
In case you want to refresh your properties with the updated one. First, you need to use annotation `@RefreshScope` on the Spring boot Main application class or on that class which is holding those properties which you need to refresh. Second, You Call this URL :`http://<yourserver>:8080/refresh` which will refresh the values and replace them with newer ones.

Comment: I tried that and it seems that I need to specify both property files: the applicatyon.yml on the classpath and properties_override.yml on the file path. 
My application.yml has entry:

custom:
    property:foo

My searchLocation value is: 
classpath:/config,file:/some_location/properties_override.yml

I have a Spring bean with the property:
@Value("${custom.property}")
    private String prop;
When I start my application I get an exception:

Could not resolve placeholder 'custom.propertyt' in value "${custom.property}"

Comment: Yes, you need to specify both files. For example, your applicatyon.yml will be in "application-name/src/main/resources" and then "searchLocations:" as mentioned above will have the path of your properties_override.yml. I would suggest you put  application.yml in  "application-name/src/main/resources" and then create another directory in that with name config and put your properties_override in that. 
application.yml =>  "application-name/src/main/resources"
properties_override.yml => "application-name/src/main/resources/config"