# Java spring switch to use local properties if Spring cloud not available

Tags: java, spring, spring-cloud

I have an issue like this:

**First**,

I have a spring cloud server to get properties for my Java app
[image]

**Second:**

If the spring cloud is not available, I want my Java app use local properties

For example, my file at `D:\SOURCE-CODE\configuration\financial\financialpartner-dev.properties`

How can I config like this?

Comment: Does this help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27131143/spring-cloud-configuration-server-not-working-with-local-properties-file

Comment: That is the default way of working. You just need to point boot at the local file and make config server optional

Comment: @spencergibb Please help me in answer and I will accept your guide. Because I don't have enough experience in Java. So it can make me confused.

Comment: Please show what you have tried