# Spring Cloud Port Conflict 8888

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-cloud

I have a port conflict when starting a service and the configuration service is already running. I'm currently using Spring Boot 1.2.3.RELEASE and Spring Cloud version 1.0.0.RELEASE (tried with 1.0.1.RELEASE, same problem).

If I start the config server in port 8888 and then try to start another service, it will try to start in port 8888 even though I have specified another port. The weird thing is that this does not happen in Mac OS, it does happen in Windows and Linux.

If I start the service and then the configuration server then it all works well. The service is assigned a different port than 8888 and the configuration service port 8888.

I have tried different versions of Spring Cloud and Spring Boot and also different configurations. I tried the suggestions on [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27133478/spring-cloud-config-port-conflict) but they did not work.

Any ideas on how to solve this?

--

I managed to solve the port conflict by removing the `server.port` from the `application.yml` in the **Config Server** and moving it to the `bootstrap.yml`. I also removed the `server.port` from the `application.yml` in the **Client Service** and moved it to the `bootstrap.yml`. Below you can see how the config files look at the moment.

These are the configuration files in **Config Service**:

**bootstrap.yml**

```
server:
  port: 8888

info:
  name: "Config Service"

spring:
  application:
    name: config-service
  profiles:
    active: native
  cloud:
    config:
      enabled: true
      server:
        git:
          uri: <url to config repo>
```

**application.yml**

```
management:
  context-path: /admin

info:
  configuration: "Read From Config Service application.yml"

endpoints:
  restart:
    enabled: true
  shutdown:
    enabled: true
  health:
    sensitive: false

logging:
  level:
    com.netflix.discovery: 'OFF'
    org.springframework.cloud: 'DEBUG'

eureka:
  instance:
    leaseRenewalIntervalInSeconds: 10
    leaseExpirationDurationInSeconds: 5
    preferIpAddress: false
    statusPageUrlPath: /admin/info
    healthCheckUrlPath: /admin/health
    metadataMap:
      hostname: ${vcap.application.application_uris[0]}
      instanceId: ${vcap.application.instance_id:${spring.application.name}:${spring.application.instance_id:${random.value}}}
  client:
    registerWithEureka: true
    fetchRegistry: true
    serviceUrl:
      defaultZone: http://127.0.0.1:8761/eureka/
```

The configuration in the **Client Service** is:

**bootstrap.yml**

```
server:
  port: 0

info:
  name: "Client Service"

spring:
  application:
    name: serviceC
  profiles:
    active: native
  cloud:
    config:
      enabled: true
      failFast: true
      env: default
      label: master
      uri: http://localhost:8888
```

The **application.yml** is empty.

Now I have another issue. In Linux the **Client** is getting the configuration from the `application.yml` file in the **Config Server** (the origin of the port conflict) and in Mac OS it getting it from the configured git repository.

What should be the correct behaviour?

Comment: you'll need to post your configuration, because the ports that the servers run on is all spring-boot.

Comment: For some reason I haven't managed to figure out yet, the configuration service and clients are behaving different in Mac OS than in Linux.

I will post the configuration.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Finally got it working.**

The problem was the `profiles.active: native` setting. The **Configuration Service** on **Linux** was getting the configuration from the local `application.yml`. For some reason this setting was not working on **Mac OS** and the Configuration Service was getting the configuration from the **Repo**.

In the end I removed the `profiles.active: native` setting and moved the common configuration to the Repo. Now all services are getting the common configuration from `application.properties` in git.