# Spring Cloud Config client not loading the value from config server

Tags: maven, spring-boot, spring-cloud-config

I am facing below issue while I try to run my Spring Cloud Config Client:

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Could not resolve placeholder 'DATABASE_NAME' in string value "${DATABASE_NAME}"
    at org.springframework.util.PropertyPlaceholderHelper.parseStringValue(PropertyPlaceholderHelper.java:174)
    at org.springframework.util.PropertyPlaceholderHelper.replacePlaceholders(PropertyPlaceholderHelper.java:126)
    at org.springframework.core.env.AbstractPropertyResolver.doResolvePlaceholders(AbstractPropertyResolver.java:204
```

My dependencies in **POM.xml** are as below:

```
<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>1.3.6.RELEASE</version>
    <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
</parent>

<dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-config</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.1.RELEASE</version>
            <type>pom</type>
            <scope>import</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-dependencies</artifactId>
            <version>Brixton.SR3</version>
            <type>pom</type>
            <scope>import</scope>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>
</dependencyManagement>

<dependencies>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-config</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

</dependencies>
```

The **bootstrap.yml**

```
spring:
application:
name: my-config-client
cloud:
services:
  registrationMethod: route
config:
  enabled: true
  uri: http://localhost:${config.port:8888}
```

The **application.yml** is as below:

```
# HTTP Server
server:
port: 2222

# Spring properties
spring:
  profiles: 
    active: dev

#Disable HTTP Basic Authentication
security:
  basic:
    enabled: false
```

The class where I am trying to access the property is as below:

```
@RefreshScope
@Component
public class MyProperty {

    @Value("${DATABASE_NAME}")
    private String databaseName;


    public String getDatabaseName() {
        return databaseName;
    }
}
```

My config server is running fine. When I use this url on browser http://localhost:8888/configserver/dev, It gives the below result:

```
{  
   "name":"configserver",
   "profiles":[  
      "dev"
   ],
   "label":"master",
   "version":"c991526a93fb776e37e18e138c7485d894d6ea4f",
   "propertySources":[  
      {  
         "name":"https://onestash.abc.com/scm/kapmol/microservice-config-repo.git/configserver.properties",
         "source":{  
            "DATABASE_NAME":"ABC",
            "CONVERT_USERS":"Y",
            "LRDS_JNDI_NAME":"jdbc/tds_new"
         }
      }
   ]
}
```

I tried with all the posts who were facing this issue. But, it is not working for me. May be, I am missing some points. If anybody can provide help, it would be great.

Thanks

Answer (score 9):

There are some breaking changes with the new spring cloud module read more: [here.](https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-release/wiki/Spring-Cloud-2020.0-Release-Notes#breaking-changes)

> Bootstrap, provided by spring-cloud-commons, is no longer enabled by
> default. If your project requires it, it can be re-enabled by
> properties or by a new starter.
>
> - To re-enable by properties set spring.cloud.bootstrap.enabled=true or spring.config.use-legacy-processing=true. These need to be set as
>   an environment variable, java system property or a command line
>   argument.
> - The other option is to include the new spring-cloud-starter-bootstrap

It worked for me by adding these dependencies:

```
<parent>
  <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
  <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-parent</artifactId>
  <version>2020.0.0</version>
  <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
</parent>
```

```
<dependencyManagement>
   <dependencies>
     <dependency>
       <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
       <artifactId>spring-cloud-dependencies</artifactId>
       <version>${spring-cloud.version}</version>
       <type>pom</type>
       <scope>import</scope>
       </dependency>
     </dependencies>
</dependencyManagement>
```

```
    <dependency>
       <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
       <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-bootstrap</artifactId>
    </dependency>
       <dependency>
       <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
       <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-config</artifactId>
     </dependency>
```

Comment: This lead me to the right fix thank you! Just a side note: all I needed was the `spring-cloud-starter-bootstrap` dependency and it picked up `bootstrap.yaml` without any issues.

Comment: Wasted almost 3 hours to find out what is the problem and yes, as always spring guys have changed some internals and now we need to add `spring-cloud-starter-bootstrap` to make it work.

Comment: I had similar problems myself, but I ran my spring program under  linux command strace which reported every file that my program  accessed.  It was some what surprised to discover that it did not access bootstrap.yml

Answer (score 1):

I referred [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26786865/spring-cloud-configuration-server-ignores-configuration-properties-file) answered by 'spencergibb' and able to resolve the issue. I added **"spring.config.name"** in my bootstrap.yml file of client application and resolved the issue. Now, my **bootstrap.yml** look like as below:

```
spring:
  application:
    name: my-config-client
  cloud:
    services:
      registrationMethod: route
  config:
    name: configserver
    enabled: true
    uri: http://localhost:${config.port:8888}
```

Comment: where did you get "${config.port:8888}" from